# How to preserve browser-loaded files on git push?

Tags: git, openshift

How can I upload files to e.g. wordpress media via the browser or install plugins via the browser and then add those changes to my repo?

I don't know how to, so any changes I make to the repo means those uploaded files get deleted when doing

```
git push
```

(I'm on openshift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a local setup, and upload those files locally, then git commit, then git push locally and git pull on the production server.

Comment: Other users also upload files via the browser.  How can I get a copy of them into my local setup?

Comment: In that case I would make file uploads to upload files to S3, then you don't have to worry about the images disappearing since they are al hosted on S3 bucket. WP plugins are pretty buggy, last time I tried this it didn't work. You milage may vary. There is a answer about this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595713/upload-files-to-amazon-s3-from-wordpress

Comment: If this is running on a single box and not on a cluster of machines behind a load balancer, you could create a php script that will do a `git commit -am 'added uploads' && git push origin`, this is hack, but it would work. Ideally you would want to structure it so to take growth into account, so S3 is the best bet, for when you do introduce a load balancer or deploy on ElasticBeanstalk

Comment: Your welcome, users on stackoverflow have helped me quite a bit over the years, so this is my way of giving back. Even though I am a little late to the party, better late than never.